# Find the general solution of this ED $y"-2y'+2y = \beta e^t \sin t $, with $\beta = 8$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Friends, I need your help again to know if the procedure I have used to solve this exercise and the result are correct.

Find the general solution of this ED

$y"-2y'+2y = \beta e^t \sin t $, with $\beta = 8$.

First I have solved the associated homogeneous equation with the same method as in the previous exercise
$y''-2y'+2y=0$ to obtain the general solution of the homogeneous equation, $y_h$.
Then I have looked for a particular solution of the complete ODE, $y_p$, with the method of indeterminate coefficients.
Once obtained, the general solution of the complete ODE is $y(t)=y_h(t)+y_p(t)$

The related homogeneous equation
$y"-2y'+2y=0$
is
$y=e^{rx}$
where
$r^2-2r+2=0$, so
$r_1 =\frac{-(-2)+2i}{2}=1±i$
Thus,
$y=e^{t}(C_1\cos(t)+C_2\sin(t))$

In the characteristic equation; I get $r=1\pm i$; Regarding the particular solution, you have to look for one of the type $y_p(t)=te^t(A\cos t +B\sin t)$.

The derivatives that I have obtained are the following:
$y_p= te^t (A \cos(t)+ B \sin(t))$

$y'_p= e^t((A + At + Bt)\cos(t)+(B-At+Bt)\sin(t))$

$y"_p= 2e^t(A + B+ Bt)\cos(t)-(A-B+At)\sin(t))$

So :
$2e^t(A + B+ Bt)\cos(t)-(A-B+At)\sin(t))-2(e^t((A + At + Bt)\cos(t)+(B -At+Bt)\sin(t)))+2(te^t (A \cos(t)+ B \sin(t))= 8e^t \sin (t)$

$-2A(t) \sin(t)+B(t)\sin(t)+2Be^t\sin(t)-A\sin(t)+2Be^t\cos(t)= 8e^t\sin(t)$

The exponential is simplified, and by identifying the coefficients of the cosine and sine of both members of the equality, the system is obtained:
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2(A+B+Bt)-2(A+At+Bt)+2At=0\\-2(A-B+At)-2( B-At+Bt)+2Bt=8\end{array}\right.\Longleftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l}2B=0\\-2A=8\end{array}\right.$ then $\boxed{B=0}$, $\boxed{A=-4}$

with $B=0$ and $A=-4$; I have already obtained the particular solution $y_p(t)=-4te^t\cos t$ with which the general solution of the complete equation becomes

$y(t) =y_h(t)+y_p(t)=C_1e^t\cos t+C_2e^t\sin t -4te^t\cos t$

with $C_1,C_2\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I see that Wolfram gives me a different result, could I have done it wrong? The result is reversed to what I have done, I hope you can understand me and clear my doubts please

Comment: I don't think your answer has any problem.

Comment: thanks, very much Friends

Comment: I did some easy format-clean-up, putting back-slashes on "cos" and "sin", which repairs the spacing problems... :)